# Beta regression or fixed effect regression

Tags: regression, panel-data, fixed-effects-model, beta-distribution

I am using panel data for 27 different countries in 5 different time periods. My IV and DV both are in fractional form (0,1), i.e., in percentages.
Please guide me, if beta regression is appropriate or I should go with a fixed-effect model, as the T is 5?
If I use beta regression, how can I get country-fixed effects?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why it should be one or the other. You can fit a beta GLM with fixed effects foor country, if that's what you want, though with 27 countries I would be inclined to fit random intercepts for country.

Comment: I read that beta regression is more suitable for cross-sectional data than for panel data, which is why I asked, which one is more appropriate?

Comment: Where did you read that ? If you have a response that is constrained in (0,1), that's a primary use cas for beta regression. Gamma is another option.

Comment: Somebody mentioned this on a response to a query on statalist website. He said, it depends on T, where in case of a higher T, the proper panel estimation options should be used. If the T is not big, beta/fractional regressions can be used.

Comment: Why though ? Anyway, I don't see a problem with beta or gamma regresson.